# sl4j version used with Jetty8

Tags: jetty, version, slf4j

Which version of sl4j is used in Jetty8. There is no sl4j provided with the Jetty8.1 distribution and several attempts to get a compatible version of sl4j for this has failed. Is there a link from where this compatible sl4j can be downloaded. As of now sl4j in the current setup that I have created sl4j is not used at all. But I want to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Define in jetty-project pom.xml in version 8.0.0.M3 :

```
<slf4j-version>1.5.11</slf4j-version>
```

Answer (score 1):

The slf4j version is 1.6.1 as you can see [in the POM](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-project/8.1.7.v20120910/jetty-project-8.1.7.v20120910.pom) for version 8.1.7. Use maven and you won't have problems with dependencies.

Comment: So it depends on which version you are using :) Just check in parent project pom.xml file, jetty-project